# 18.04: microSDXC Card Reader [Hama 00091047] is not working after update

Tags: drivers, 18.04, usb, realtek, card-reader

I've a problem after update to ...
  Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 5.3.0-28-generic
      Architecture: x86-64

I can still see the USB adapter ...
sudo lsusb | grep Realtek
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0bda:0109 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

but I can't mount the device. A modprobe rts0109 will return
modprobe: FATAL: Module rts0109 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.3.0-28-generic

Any hint for me?

Uwe

Comment: Try `modprobe rts5139` ([source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/824273))

Comment: same result, but an exchange of the SD card was successful. The orig. card is still usable in the camera. strange ...